# jQuery как получить текст

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите плиз, как в jQuery получить текст "Hotels"

`<span class="dlposts-found__current-page-label"><i>·</i>Hotels</span>`

если я делаю так:

`jQuery( ".dlposts-found__current-page-label" ).text();`

то получаю: `·Hotels·Hotels`

а если так:

`jQuery( ".dlposts-found__current-page-label" ).html();`

`<i>·</i>Hotels`

```
`<strong>
    <span class="dlposts-found__of">30</span>
    <span class="dlposts-found__number-separator">of</span>
    <span class="dlposts-found__number">530</span>
    <span class="dlposts-found__label">results</span>
    <span class="dlposts-found__current-page-label"><i>·</i>Hotels</span>
</strong>`
```

Comment: то получаю: `·Hotels·Hotels` - у Вас их два?

Comment: Нет, один, я сам не знаю как так получается

Comment: А вы попробуйте прямо в консоли на странице выполнить этот код: `jQuery( ".dlposts-found__current-page-label" ).length;`

Comment: да, в консоли. В этот span данные подставляются JS'ом после выбора результата в дропдауне

Comment: В этом случае решение простое - точнее определять селектор. Не искать глобально, а в конкретном элементе.

Comment: Я вроде и так точно определил селектор, но туда попадает содержимое тега `<i>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var label = jQuery( ".dlposts-found__current-page-label" ).text();
console.log( label.replace('·', '') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="dlposts-found__current-page-label"><i>·</i>Hotels</span>
```

Comment: Это решение? А если точка используется в тексте, который должен остаться? А если внутри `<i>` будет не точка?

Comment: @Igor, тут я соглашусь, нужны варианты какие могут быть, а то может даже и не быть совсем никакого символа впереди

Answer (score 2):

```js
var $clone = $(".dlposts-found__current-page-label").clone();
$clone.children().remove();
console.log($clone.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="dlposts-found__current-page-label"><i>·</i>Hotels</span>
```

Comment: При выполнении кода, перед Hotels '·'

Comment: @eugene_v Я должен каким-то образом понять, что означает эта фраза?

Comment: нажмите на кнопку "Выполнить код" и посмотрите результат, там точка перед Hotels

Comment: @eugene_v Это уже лучше. Вы смотрите на страницу, где отрендерен html, или на вывод в консоли?